# AttributeError: 'TabularDataset' object has no attribute 'unique' in Autogluon

Tags: python, pytorch, automl

I have the problem described in the title when running my own dataset with *autogluon*, but not when using the dataset downloaded from the web in the tutorial. I have made my dataset in csv format.

there is my code.
target=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','Lf']
features=['miuH','rhoH','YH_OC','YH_O2','YH_N']

```
train_df=TabularDataset('train_df.csv')
test_df=TabularDataset('test_df.csv')

predictor = TabularPredictor(label=target).fit(
    train_df[features+target],
    tuning_data=test_df[features+target],
    time_limit=240
    )
```

And there is part of my dataset:

```
Unnamed: 0    miuH      rhoH  ...             H4            H5        Lf
0           0  2.7500   80000.0  ...   76131.310000  7.699976e+04  0.000680
1           1  1.6250  140000.0  ...   69323.414000  6.419696e+04  0.000704
2           2  3.8750   40000.0  ...   39790.990000  3.989756e+04  0.000382
3           3  1.0625  100000.0  ...       0.000054  2.731176e-12  0.000403
4           4  3.3125  160000.0  ...  111573.800000  1.188784e+05  0.000579

[5 rows x 17 columns]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "label" in TabularPredictor is a string (column where the target class is) not a list, [see](https://auto.gluon.ai/dev/api/autogluon.predictor.html#autogluon.tabular.TabularPredictor).
Maybe that it's the problem.